# pretentious happy faces

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I am wondering if the following sentence reflects a correct usage of pretentious:

*She put on a pretentious happy face.*

The definition of pretentious says "**adjective** attempting to impress by affecting greater importance, talent, culture, etc., than is actually possessed"

I do not know if pretentious can be used as compound adjective.

What other features can etc. include in the definition of pretentious?

Comment: I think it is an incorrect usage. Without context, it is hard to be sure what the writer intended. Perhaps they thought pretentious was similar in meaning to pretend? If so, maybe counterfeit would be a better adjective?

Comment: No; 'false' works better here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But whether one uses "false" or "pretentious", doesn't it need to be "falsely happy face" or "pretentiously happy face"?

Comment: @WS2 Why don't you check usage with a Google search? 'Falsely happy face' would use the adjective-modifier (traditionally, adverb) 'falsely', whereas 'false happy face' would use 'false' to modify the noun phrase 'happy face'. Some examples include a comma, which I'd not say was appropriate. 'Happy face' may not be as unitary as 'fake diamond', but you wouldn't dream of using 'largely fake diamond'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Wouldn't that depend on whether "large" was qualifying "diamond" or "fake"? Diamond is perhaps not a good example because I'm not sure that one can be partly fake and partly genuine. But say the noun is "story". "A large fake story" is a different thing to "a largely fake story".

Comment: @WS2 Why do you think I chose 'diamond'? I'd say '[a] happy face' is a close enough collocation, even when not the emoticon sense, to license 'a false happy face'. Probably as a result of 'put on a happy face' from, if I remember correctly, a musical / song. Though 'a falsely happy face' is of course not unacceptable per se, I'd say that 'a false happy face' sounds more natural. // 'Pretentious[ly] happy face' are similarly grammatical, but I'd say so unnatural sounding they should be avoided.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A pretentiously clever lawyer? Would you change that?

Comment: I wouldn't use it, full stop. What does 'pretentiously clever' mean? 'Pretentious' refers to a person, and I don't see 'pretentiously' as being natural modifying an adjective. But 'pretentious' and 'clever' could individually modify 'lawyer'. Using them together would be like referring to a 'vicious expensive dog'. Some descriptors don't stack naturally.

Comment: But a "viciously expensive dog" would have a different meaning to a "vicious and expensive dog". And how about "a pretentiously awkward student"?

Comment: How can pretentious modify awkward? The student is pretending to be awkward to convince people of something? Now I would believe "pretentiously expensive dress" as I happen to know people buy designer clothes they really can't afford in order to impress.

Comment: I mostly agree with Edwin that pretentious (as we've been discussing it here; evidently it can also mean ambitious) refers to a person...it refers to a motivation for a person to own, use, or flaunt something. So it can be used to modify objects as well. A pretentious house is one intended to convince others of the owner's status or wealth. A pretentious accent is something affected to suggest high status, education, or birth. I guess in some contexts one might stretch the normal usage and use "pretentiously happy face" but it is not, to my American ears, a natural phrase, even with the -ly.

Comment: pretentious as a compound adjective? What does that even mean?? pretentiously happy sounds like a snob to me.

Comment: You can have a "gormless happy face", a "tranquil happy face", a "sinister happy face", a "gloating happy face"... I'm sure in some context you could have a "pretentious happy face", like people who laugh hollowly at Shakespearean comedies to show how erudite they are. Maybe if you affect a pleased expression when you hear an experimental theatre troupe is doing a 19-hour adaptation of A Man Without Qualities nearby.

Comment: But a [compound adjective](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/adjectives_compound_adjectives.htm) is something like "fat-free" or "ten-mile", it's not a single word. So that part of the question is indeed nonsensical.

Comment: She is pretending to have a happy face: A pretend happy face. **Most likely not pretentious**.

Comment: A face can be pretentious, and can be happy, and can be both. I don't know what "compound adjective" means here.

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest her self-awareness can be conveyed by saying 'she **put on** a happy face.'

**A** If she was happy, and also thought she had some status to maintain, then 'pretentious happy face' is good.
You are saying that her face expressed both genuine happiness and pretentious aspiration.

**B** If she believed it was important to show that she was happy, even if she was actually worried or miserable, because she had to maintain her status, then she might 'put on a pretentiously happy face.'
In that case, everyone could see that her  appearance of happiness was all a charade to boost her social importance.